# How to change preference for SectionList section index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have a single array of data source which is having multiple types of groups like "Groups I Manage", "Group I belong" and "Favourite Groups". By default, SectionList showing the "Favourite Groups" section at the end but I wan to show it at first. How should I do it? Kindly help.

My Code:

```
<SectionList
                renderItem={({ index, section }) =>
                  this._renderGroups(section.data[index], section.title, index)
                }
                stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
                renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
                  <View style={styles.headerTiltle}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        ...CommonStyles.Header1Style(20)
                      }}
                    >
                      {this.state.appString[title]}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                )}
                sections={this.state.dataSource}
               // sections={[{ data: this.state.dataSource, index:2 }, { data: this.state.dataSource, index:0 }, {data: this.state.dataSource, index:1}]}
                // sections={[
                //   {title: "Favourite Groups", data: this.state.dataSource},
                //   {title: "Groups I Manage", data: this.state.dataSource},
                //   {title: "Groups I Belong To", data: this.state.dataSource}
                // ]}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to change the sequence of adding data to the final array.

```
var respArray = [];
if (favouriteGroups.length)
  favouriteGroups.map((item) => {
      item.s3photo = getSignedUrl( item.photo );
  });
  respArray.push({
    title: 'lbl_favourite_groups',
    data: favouriteGroups,
  });
if (managed_by.length)
  managed_by.map((item) => {
      item.s3photo = getSignedUrl( item.photo );
  });
  respArray.push({
    title: 'lbl_groups_i_manage',
    data: managed_by,
  });
if (belongs_to.length)
  belongs_to.map((item) => {
      item.s3photo = getSignedUrl( item.photo );
  });
  respArray.push({
    title: 'lbl_groups_i_belongs_to',
    data: belongs_to,
  });
```